# Maven - how to get build date time of an artifact?

Tags: maven

Is there a way to display build date time of an artifact using mvn cli?

Context: Say I have a dependency with version eq RELEASE (Maven downloads latest release version of such an artifact for every build) and need to know its build date and time.

Comment: There is no such information stored only by a way of extracting it from the pom.properties but i don't see the need to do that? What exact problem do you have? If you write `RELEASE` do you mean a release from the maven perspective or are we talking about a SNAPSHOT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the build was performed with maven and you're not responsible for it, you can check in the jar's `META-INF/maven/<groupId>/<artifactId>/pom.properties`.

It's possible though that this information is missing due to specific plugins, maven versions, etc.

I do not recomment using this technique to automatically extract information. This is good if it's a one-of, without guarantees of success.

The content of the pom.properties is like the following:

```
#Generated by Maven
#Fri Aug 07 17:02:37 CEST 2015
version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
groupId=be.ogregoire
artifactId=tets
```

What interests you is the 2nd line. But as it is commented, don't use a  `Properties` object to read it.

Also, I admit I don't know any cli way to check this.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) plugin should solve your requirement. You can use it like this:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <doCheck>true</doCheck>
          <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

afterwards you'll be able to modify the final name, i.e.

```
  <build>
    <finalName>$\{project.artifactId}-$\{project.version}-r$\{buildNumber}</finalName>
  </build>
```

similarly, in order to use a date of a build within your `POM`, take advantage of [buildnumber:create-timestamp](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-timestamp-mojo.html).

Comment: I think OP is asking build data time information of the dependencies.

Comment: `<finalName>...</finalName>` will change only the name in your local target folder but the not the name of the artifact which is deployed/installed by `mvn deploy / mvn install`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare pom's property:

`<maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>`

or chosen date format.

Then using resources filtering or placing in `src/main/resources` a file:

**Example**

`BuildInfo.properties`

```
buildDate=${buildDate}
```